# Run shell command from jar?

Tags: java, shell, jar, executable-jar

The usual way to call a shell command from java is something like that:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

and works usually fine.
But now I've exported my project to an executable jar file and callig shell commands doesn't work any more. Are there any explanations, solutions or workarounds for this problem?

phineas

--

edit:

- even keyboard interrupts (ctrl+c; ctrl+d) aren't recognized.
- terminal input won't work after killing java

--

Smallest programm:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
    public static String fileName = "";

    /** test if you can open a 7z archive file with a given password */
    public static boolean test(String password)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String command = "7z l "+fileName;

        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        OutputStream out = process.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter w = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(w);
        writer.write(password+"\n");
        writer.close();
        w.close();
        out.close();

        if(process.waitFor() == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        fileName = args[0];
        test(args[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: what error do you get if any?

Comment: no error, no exception, nothing. it totally confuses me.

Comment: what is the smallest program you can write and export to a jar that exhibits this behaviour?

Comment: I apologize for the dumb question, but it's worth asking...does this work if you run it from an IDE or does it never work?

Comment: yes it works I use eclipse ide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run your test program and use `ps` or the task manager you will notice that `7z` is running. Your issue is that you are not consuming the output of the Process. So `7z` is quickly blocked trying to output your archive's contents.

If you add just before the `process.waitFor()` the following lines you'll get a working program:

```
    InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[256];
    while (true) {
        int c = in.read(buf);
        if (c == -1)
            break;
        System.out.println(new String(buf));
    }
```

However this will only consume the process stdout you need to do the same with `process.getErrorStream()`. You may find it easier to use `ProcessBuilder` to launch your process as it allows you to merge the stderr and stdout streams.

Comment: Of course I supposed there are no issue with the command path.

Answer (score 2):

You should read this excellent [JavaWorld article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=1) on the pitfalls of running external processes from Java.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that your issue is with the base path from which the command is executed. There is a way to set it explicitly when invoking exec.